# jFilechooser show folder

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to show the parent folder of current directory in jfilechooser.
I want to display that folder with `..` which refers to the parent folder

Comment: `jfilechooser.setCurrentDirectory(jfilechooser.getCurrentDirectory().getParent())`??  This will throw a `null` pointer exception if you're at a root level folder...

Comment: like other folders are there when we go in any directory i want to show parent directory also...when anyone click on that folder.. its moves out of the current directory and go in its parent directory

Comment: So, you want to display something like a tree, with the parent folder as the root node and the files within it as child nodes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I guess OP wants to display that folder with `..` which refers to the parent folder.

Comment: @HarryJoy The question was a little vague to start with, now has a pretty picture to help explain things ;)

Comment: @ Harry Joy I want exactly what you said

Comment: Then you should update your question to be more clear on your requirement.

Comment: i have updated..please help now

Comment: @Problems I can make it work, but you will lose the extended "directory" selection from the top view.

Comment: @ MadProgrammer i am okay with it..i dont need that

Comment: @MadProgrammer please make it work

Answer (score 3):

Use the constructor which takes file path as argument like this.

`JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(".\\..");`

Check out [`JFileChooser(File currentDirectory)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#JFileChooser%28java.io.File%29).

Comment: We're up to Java 7 now, Java 1.4.2 is a little out of date for most people...IMHO

Answer (score 2):

This is an "attempt" to implement the functionality that you request, the problem I have is that it's not possible replicate entirely what the system is doing.

Basically, the directory combo box is expecting some kind of native `File` object (in the case of Windows, a `sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2`).  But there doesn't seem to be any way by which we can create them from within the provided API (and you won't want to create them manually, as it will break the Look and Feel and cross platform functionality).

[image]

```
import core.util.MethodInvoker;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;

public class TestFileChooser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(new MyFileSystemView());
                fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyFileSystemView extends FileSystemView {

        @Override
        public File[] getFiles(File dir, boolean useFileHiding) {
            File[] files = super.getFiles(dir, useFileHiding);

            List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(files));
            if (!isFileSystemRoot(dir)) {
                File newPath = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().createFileObject(dir, "/..");
                fileList.add(0, newPath);
            }
            files = fileList.toArray(files);

            return files;
        }

        @Override
        public File createNewFolder(File containingDir) throws IOException {
            File newFolder = new File(containingDir + File.separator + "New Folder");
            if (!newFolder.mkdir()) {
                newFolder = null;
            }
            return newFolder;
        }
    }
}
```